# Dynamics: EQ-States vs. NESS-States

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with dynamics $\tau$.

Consider a state that relaxes towards equilibrium:
$$\omega_T(A):=\omega\circ\tau^T(A)\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\omega_\infty(A)$$

Then it relaxes in mean towards equilibrium, too:
$$\langle\omega\rangle_T(A):=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\omega\circ\tau^s(A)\mathrm{d}s\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\omega_\infty(A)$$
That is it has a unique steady-state: $\omega_\text{NESS}=\omega_\text{EQ}$

Intuitively, convergence implies convergence in mean but how to prove it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After a while it's not as hard...*

In fact, local integrability is the key:
$$\omega\circ\tau(A)\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+):\quad\omega_T(A)\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\omega_\infty\implies\langle\omega\rangle_T\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\omega_\infty$$
*(See the thread: [Asymptotic Convergence vs. Mean Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098577/79762))*