# Mollifiers: Asymptotic Convergence vs. Mean Convergence

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**

> Does asymptotic convergence imply mean convergence:
>   $$\varphi\in\mathcal{L}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}_+):\quad\varphi(T)\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\varphi_\infty\implies\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\varphi(s)\mathrm{d}s\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\varphi_\infty$$

**Remark**

Three important classes fall under local integrability: $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}_+),\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{L}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}_+)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the integral gives:
$$\left|\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\varphi(s)\mathrm{d}s-\varphi_\infty\right|\leq\frac{1}{T}\int_0^{T_\varphi}|\varphi(s)|\mathrm{d}s+\frac{1}{T}\int_{T_\varphi}^T|\varphi(s)-\varphi_\infty|\mathrm{d}s+\frac{1}{T}\int_0^{T_\varphi}|\varphi_\infty|\\\leq\delta_T\left(\int_0^\infty|\varphi(s)|\mathrm{d}s\right)+1\cdot\delta_\varphi+\delta_T\cdot T_\varphi|\varphi_\infty|=\varepsilon\quad(T\geq T_\infty\geq\delta_T^{-1}T_\varphi)$$

*(The first and third integral were bounded while the second integral was approximated.)*

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer: Writing it out explicitely? *(In any case vote-up. Thanks. :))*

Comment: @Freeze_S: Please feel free to edit. I wanted to give a hint and not a full solution. But if you want to edit- be my guest :)

Comment: There's still a flaw as the middle term doesn't vanish yet. I remember splitting it with squareroot somehow. *(Maybe I or you can fix that.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: Isn't the middle term $\leq \epsilon (T-T_0)/T?$

Comment: Ah right! ...btw, I just noticed the first term can be handled also by the weaker condition of local integrability.

Comment: @Freeze_S: I think that's right too.

Comment: I will add this to the assumptions in the question. You're answer remains still true. ;) *(The point is that my setting usually has continuity.)*

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20141/discussion-between-freeze-s-and-voldemort).

Comment: You are welcome :)